# PHP function using on.click and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm completely new to stack overflow and a reasonably new dev, I've come across my first ajax function and unfortunately although I have read about 20 posts I still cannot figure out how I need to implement my function. Once I have it down how I can perform one function I can usually get anything else to work.

I have a "tasks" system that I'm building, I have 2 functions within php, 1 lists all the overdue tasks, and the other a removes tasks function,

The tasks are listed in bootstrap alert div's based upon priority and due date, within each of the alerts I have 2 buttons, 1 dismiss, 2 completed, I have a function within php to mark the task with a status of "2".

Here's what i have so far.

This is what is generated by my 1st function which works perfectly

```
<div class='alert alert-danger fade in'>
    <strong>Task: </strong><?php echo $row[1];?>     <strong class="myAlerts">Note: </strong><?php echo $row[5];?><strong class="myAlerts">Due Date: </strong><?php echo $row[2];?>
    <div class='pull-right'>
    <button class='close' style='margin-right: 10px;' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='dismiss'>Completed
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle'></span>
    </button>
    <button action="removeTask()" class='close' style='margin-right: 10px;' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='dismiss'>dismiss
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></span>
    </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is php code that performs the completion of the task, which is located in Functions/functions.php

My dashboard.php calls the function ODTasks() and below is the function I need to call by clicking on the completed button (without leaving the modal or page I'm on)

```
function removeTask($TaskName,$taskID){

    if (isset($TaskName)){
    echo "Taskname is set"; 
    }
    else {
    header ('Location: index.php?error="Task completion variables not set [E/1]"'); 
    }

    if (isset($TaskID)){
    echo "TaskID is set";
    }
    else {
    header ('Location: index.php?error="Task completion variables not set [E/2]"'); 
    }

    if (file_exists('../database/mysqli_connection.php')){
    require('../database/mysqli_connection.php');
    } else {
    require('database/mysqli_connection.php');  
    }

    $updateTask = "UPDATE MC_Tasks SET status='2' WHERE TaskName ='".$TaskName."' AND TaskId='".$taskID."'";

    $completedTaskResult = mysqli_query($mysqli_connection,$updateTask);

    if (mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli_connection) > 0){
    echo "task Completed!"; 
    } else {
    echo "Task could not be removed, lets check the query on what went wrong";
    echo $updateTask;
    }
}
```

This is what im testing for the AJAX

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function removeTask() {
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '<?php Thisurl();?>',
           data:{action:'removeTask'},
           success:function(html) {
             alert(html);
           }

      });
 }
 
 </script>
```

Added this to the dashboard.php
but I get no echo from it :(

```php
<?php
//added for removing a task
if($_POST['action'] == 'removeTask') {
echo "try removing this task";
/* will soon be calling the function with this once the echo works
removeTask($TaskName,$taskID);
*/
}   
?>
```

Comment: What's your question?  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please spend a few minutes at [help] to see how to ask a question. In this case we do not see any ajax and you have not specified what exactly does not work.

Comment: hey guys sorry i missed the ajax, it should be there now, im also adding a little snippet i added at the bottom of the dashboard.php which is what im using at the moment to try this function

Comment: Have you confirmed that removeTask() is being called? Add an alert() or console.log() inside the function to check. Also check out the XHR request in Chrome dev tools if using Chrome or Firebug if using FireFox. Is the request payload what you're expecting? What does the response look like?

Comment: Hey so i've managed to get the onClick working now, that was my mistake I put action= rather than onlick= now i need it to perform the post into the page which will then perform the function, Not return the page in an alert.

Answer (score 0):

Remove button action and add onClick

```
<button onClick="removeTask()" class='close' style='margin-right: 10px;' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='dismiss'>dismiss 
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></span> 
</button>
```

Comment: Nitpicky comment: should be "onclick", not "onClick" :P

Comment: ooops that was a typo, but in the code i have the right one

Comment: Hi yeah I spotted that one *face palm*.... but my ajax is rubbish, i need it to post action:removeTask so that the php can pick it up and perform the function.

Comment: Its not resolved, I still need help with AJAX, I need the ajax to to run that removeTask function with the $TaskName,$taskID